# Making a nested CSS menu responsive (100% width)

Tags: html, css

I made a menu already:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li>Menu 1
        <ul class="nav first">
            <li>Menu 111</li>
            <li>Menu 22</li>
            <li>Menu 3333</li>
            <li>Menu 44
            <ul class="nav">
                <li>Menu 111111</li>
                <li>Menu 22</li>
                <li>Menu 3333</li>
                <li>Menu 44</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Menu 2222</li>
    <li>Menu 33</li>
    <li>Menu 4444444</li>
</ul>

#nav, .nav, #nav .nav li { margin:0px; padding:0px; }

#nav li {float:left; display:inline; cursor:pointer; list-style:none; padding:0px 10px 0px 10px; border:1px #000 solid; position:relative;}

#nav li ul.first {left:-1px; top:100%;}

li, li a {color:#000; text-decoration:none;}

#nav .nav li { width: 100%; text-indent:10px; line-height:30px; margin-right:10px; border-top:1px #000 solid; border-bottom:1px #000 solid;
border-left:none; border-right:none; background:#fff;}
#nav li a {display:block; width:inherit; height:inherit;}

ul.nav { display:none; }
#nav li:hover > a, #nav li:hover { color:#fff; background:#000; }
li:hover > .nav { display:block; position:absolute; width:200px; top:-2px; left:100%; z-index:1000; border:1px #000 solid; }
li:hover { position:relative; z-index:2000; }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/L8VPk/

there are two things missing:

- When navigating in a sub menu, I want the column be as wide as the widest item (so like it was all a table)
- There are 4 main columns, they should have 25% 25% 25% 25% widths, so auto stretch the browser window. But I don't want to set those widths manually (and there can be more menus)

Comment: Have You considered using display: table for the second one (2nd one thing missing)? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the parent element, `#nav` to `display:table` and the direct `li` child elements to `display:table-cell`. As [@Danko points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21314153/making-a-nested-css-menu-responsive-100-width/21314416#comment32126091_21314416), you can add `width:1%` to the child `li` elements to force them to have equal widths.

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7XYpT/)

See the updated CSS for the other changes made:

```
#nav {
    display:table;
}
#nav > li {
    cursor:pointer;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0px 10px 0px 10px;
    border:1px #000 solid;
    position:relative;
    display:table-cell;
    width:1%;
}
#nav ul li {
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
    text-indent:10px;
    line-height:30px;
    margin-right:10px;
    border-top:1px #000 solid;
    border-bottom:1px #000 solid;
    border-left:none;
    border-right:none;
    background:#fff;
    position:relative;
}
ul {
    display:none;
}
li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1000;
    border:1px #000 solid;
    left:0;
}
#nav > li ul li ul {
    left:100%;
    top:-2px;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
#nav li:hover > a, #nav li:hover {
    color:#fff;
    background:#000;
}
li, li a {
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}
* {box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;}
```

Comment: @JohnSmith The submenus look fine to me - this is what i'm getting: http://i.stack.imgur.com/g9xul.png

Comment: @Danko Thanks - I didn't realize you could do that :) Updating.

Comment: I got this: http://s17.postimg.org/gwne3o0sf/Image1.gif with the newest Firefox. Consider the scrollbars

Comment: great :)))) all I miss is to have submenus width to be determined by the lenghtest content.... so in this case "menu3333"

Comment: @JohnSmith You're saying that you *don't* want them to inherit the width? I'm not sure i'm understanding you; just let me know - i'd be happy to fix it.

Comment: yes, I dont want it. Just be as heighted as the maximum content, just like in tables (the lenght of table = longest TD

Comment: @JohnSmith My bad - I misunderstood you; this should be what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/76fXK/ let me know if it isn't.

Comment: Exactly! This kind of vertical menu should be teached, really!

Comment: oh one thing: I dont want to set 25% because the situation wont be this easy. There can be 7 menu item, with various length :)

Comment: for example, if you check those (non valid) tables, the length of columns are the same: http://jsfiddle.net/EjTtL/ without setting the width. Thats what I want to achieve.

Comment: right, in the meantime I figured it out myself. Please post it so I can accept as solution

Comment: oops, there is a mistake: http://jsfiddle.net/7XYpT/1/ the other submenus appear at the wrong place :S

Comment: @JohnSmith It worked in Chrome, I thought it was fine. I updated it; it now works in FF too - http://jsfiddle.net/7vmCZ/